# Any intelligent solution to transform matrix of transcripts to a matrix of genes?

Tags: r, algorithm, transformation

**Data explained.** Key points: (i) a single transcript is represented by a row, ENTREZID column represents genes; (ii) rows 627 and 627 have the same ENTREZID => one-to-mane relationship :: many transcripts in one gene; one transcript is be related to one gene only.

```
> head(m.venn4[m.venn4[,2]>0,])
    Irradiation_fm toluene_fm Dioxin_fm formaldehyde_fm ENTREZID
81           FALSE       TRUE     FALSE           FALSE    46717
152          FALSE       TRUE      TRUE           FALSE    31055
615          FALSE       TRUE      TRUE            TRUE    31460
626          FALSE       TRUE      TRUE            TRUE    31464
627          FALSE       TRUE      TRUE            TRUE    31464
683          FALSE       TRUE     FALSE            TRUE    3152
```

**The task.** Transform table of transcripts to a table of genes, e.g. have something like, here I have integer, but as.logical(0) == FALSE, and as.logical(3) == TRUE, so that's fine

```
> df.sum[df.sum[,5] %in% c("46717", "31055", "31460", "31464", "31464", "31529"),]
    Irradiation_fm toluene_fm Dioxin_fm formaldehyde_fm ENTREZID
81               0          1         0               0    46717
152              0          1         1               0    31055
615              0          1         1               1    31460
461              0          2         2               2    31464
683              0          1         0               1    31529
```

**The research.** To be honest, I gave it a thought, but was unable to describe the task in generic keywords in one line.

**My solution.**

```
####
#### tranform transcripts to genes
df.sum <- data.frame(Irradiation_fm=logical(),
                     toluene_fm=logical(),
                     Dioxin_fm=logical(), 
                     formaldehyde_fm=logical(),
                     ENTREZID=character(),
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dfit <- 1
for (id in unique(m.venn4$ENTREZID)) {
    if (length(m.venn4[m.venn4$ENTREZID==id,1]) > 1) {
        for (it in 1:4) {
            df.sum[dfit,it] <-  sum(m.venn4[m.venn4$ENTREZID==id,it])
        }
    } else {
        df.sum[dfit,1:4] <- m.venn4[m.venn4$ENTREZID==id,1:4]
    }
    df.sum[dfit,5] <- as.character(id)
    dfit <- dfit+1
}

m.sum <- matrix(,nrow=length(df.sum[,1]),ncol=4)

m.sum[,1] <- as.logical(df.sum[,1])
m.sum[,2] <- as.logical(df.sum[,2])
m.sum[,3] <- as.logical(df.sum[,3])
m.sum[,4] <- as.logical(df.sum[,4])
rownames(m.sum) <- df.sum[,5]
colnames(m.sum) <- c("Irradiation_fm", "toluene_fm", "Dioxin_fm", "formaldehyde_fm")
```

**The request.** Could you please show a non-ogre solution for the following code? I dislike mine because it is unintelligent and slow, -- an ogre of all humanoid creatures. I also feel that apply()-driven solutions would just have a better syntax, but would be as slow.

Comment: Isn't this just `aggregate(. ~ ENTREZID, m.venn4, sum)`??

Comment: Thank you, the solution with dplyr is almost six times faster than yours. But anyway, much faster than mine.

> paste("ogre: ", t.o2-t.o1, " :: aggregate: ", t.n2-t.n1)
[1] "ogre:  1.4621836344401  :: aggregate:  0.688039064407349"

Comment: I can you provide another fast solution if you want. Try this `library(data.table) ; setkey(setDT(m.venn4), ENTREZID)[, lapply(.SD, sum), ENTREZID]`

Comment: Sure, but I feel it would be more for curiosity, and I would return the simple test results. Both aggregate and dplyr are good enough for me.

Comment: Oh, data.table is the winner so far.

> paste("ogre: ", t.o2-t.o1, " :: data.table: ", t.n2-t.n1)
[1] "ogre:  1.4621836344401  :: data.table:  0.0140011310577393"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may `sum` each column (grouped by ENTREZID) with `summarise_each` in the `dplyr` package. The "Logical vectors are coerced to integer vectors in contexts where a numerical value is required" (see `?TRUE`).

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ENTREZID) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum))

#   ENTREZID Irradiation_fm toluene_fm Dioxin_fm formaldehyde_fm
# 1     3152              0          1         0               1
# 2    31055              0          1         1               0
# 3    31460              0          1         1               1
# 4    31464              0          2         2               2
# 5    46717              0          1         0               0
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is much faster.

> paste("ogre: ", t.o2-t.o1, " :: dplyr: ", t.n2-t.n1)
[1] "ogre:  1.4621836344401  :: dplyr:  0.12300705909729"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a comparison of the all answers:

#### Original answer:

```
t.o1 <- Sys.time()
df.sum <- data.frame(Irradiation_fm=logical(),
                     toluene_fm=logical(),
                     Dioxin_fm=logical(), 
                     formaldehyde_fm=logical(),
                     ENTREZID=character(),
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dfit <- 1
for (id in unique(m.venn4$ENTREZID)) {
    if (length(m.venn4[m.venn4$ENTREZID==id,1]) > 1) {
        for (it in 1:4) {
            df.sum[dfit,it] <-  sum(m.venn4[m.venn4$ENTREZID==id,it])
        }
    } else {
        df.sum[dfit,1:4] <- m.venn4[m.venn4$ENTREZID==id,1:4]
    }
    df.sum[dfit,5] <- as.character(id)
    dfit <- dfit+1
}
t.o2 <- Sys.time()
```

#### dplyr:

```
t.dplyr1 <- Sys.time()
df.sum2 <- m.venn4 %>% group_by(ENTREZID) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))
t.dplyr2 <- Sys.time()
```

#### aggregate:

```
t.aggr1 <- Sys.time()
df.sum2 <- aggregate(. ~ ENTREZID, m.venn4, sum)
t.aggr2 <- Sys.time()
```

#### data.table

```
library(data.table) 
t.dt1 <- Sys.time()
df.sum2 <- setkey(setDT(m.venn4), ENTREZID)[, lapply(.SD, sum), ENTREZID]
t.dt2 <- Sys.time()
```

#### Result:

```
# Method     Runtime (sec)
# ========================
# ogre               54.55
# dplyr              0.011
# aggregate           0.42
# data.table         0.006
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? It works perfectly  fine with your data set

Comment: Sry, my bad, -- haven't transformed to a data.frame before utilizing %in% operator. Thanks for the comment.

df.sum2 <- as.data.frame(df.sum2); df.sum2[df.sum2[,1] %in% c("38679", "41829", "42810", "43252", "2768691", "12798468"),]